# Data augmentation - How for every class generate different number of new data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-augmentation

I want to generate new augmented images only for specific labels. For example data base FER2013:

```
emotion_label_to_text_mapper = {0: "Angry", 2: "Fear-Disgust", 3: "Happy", 4: "Sad", 5: "Surprise"}

df = pd.read_csv('/FER2013Plus-5-emotions.csv')
    
df.emotion.unique()
sns.countplot(df.emotion)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

So, I get this number of pictures for every emotion.

Is it possible to set a ImageDataGenerator to generate for every class specific number of augmented pictures?

**Example**: to generate in the learning process new augmented data only for classes 0 or 1, add more 1000 pictures to every class.

Comment: ImageDataGenerator do not add new images to the original data.

Comment: @Frightera - To generate in the learning process

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good exploration how to train cnn with imbalanced data:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data

need to use with class_weight parameter with training process.